# Using a method to select records | Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Request table in the database and there is a method `def status` in the model that returns an integer with the current status of the request. Based on if the request is deleted/rejected or not it returns a status in the form of an integer. Now I'd like to select the requests of which the status is 10 or 20 but I don't know how to include this in the active record queries.

The status method looks like this:

```
def status
    s = 1
    s = 1 if rejected_by == false
    s = 2 if rejected_by == true

    quotations_count = quotations.length
    if quotations_count > 0
      s = 20
      s = 11 unless quotations[0].rejected_at.nil?

      s = 3  if !quotations[0].rejected_at.nil? && rejected_by == false
      booking = quotations[0].booking
      unless booking.nil?
        s = 30
        s = 35 unless quotations[0].review.nil?
      end
    end

    s
 end
```

Comment: Given all the work you're doing, have you considered storing the status in the database, so you can query it directly?

Comment: I concord with j-dexx. It's easier to add that column to the table itself. You will save a nice headache. BTW, add the code of  "rejected_by" if you are willing to do it this way.

Comment: Request.where(["status = ? or status = ?", 10, 20]) is this are you looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I have considered that. But the database's owner does not want that. @chaitanya, tried this but ruby thinks the status is a column in the table

Comment: Can you create another table with a foreign key ? Or you can create an array with a status value for each record and then query this array. But this creates à lot of unnecessary calculations. (Am beginner, there may be better solutions)